# why i can't play the full song on libgdx

Tags: java, audio, libgdx, playback

I have this sound track and I can't play it all. It always plays first of track like 5 seconds and then stops. It should be 63 seconds.

```
Sound sound;
@Override
public void create() { 
  soundback=Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("background.wav"));
  soundback.play();
}
```

Comment: Did you import   `com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The libgdx [Sound](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/audio/Sound.html) class is for small sounds that are used many times even at the same time over each other. [Music](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/audio/Music.html) however, is for longer sounds that only play one at a time like the song in the background.

```
Music music = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("data/mymusic.mp3"));
music.play();
```